# Can you save an expression as a variable

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to save an expression such as this.

```
Out-File -FilePath "C:\StartupInfo.txt"  -Append
```

To variable, I was hoping to do something like this

```
$logfile = Out-File -FilePath "C:\StartupInfo.txt" -Appened
```

I would use the variable to log the work in a text file that is done through out the script.

```
Write-OutPut "$ComputerName work completed." | $logFile
```

Comment: I'm not totally clear what you're trying to do - how are you planning on using ```$logfile``` afterwards?

Comment: A function or scriptblock might work. Please [edit] the question and explain with more details what you'd like to do. Pseudocode is fine.

Comment: I think you're looking to use `Invoke-Expression` but can't tell exactly what task you're trying to accomplish/ how you're using `$logfile`

Comment: An expression is also known as `scriptblock` in PowerShell, to save an expression into a variable you just add `{ }` opening and closing your variable and the expression you want to execute inside. `$logfile = { Out-File - FilePath "C:\StartupInfo.txt" -Appened }` and then `& $logfile` to execute it.

Comment: I've updated my questions @vonPryz hopefully that helps explain what I'm trying to do.